# What is the reasoning behind 0 mixin for Aeon?

Tags: cryptonote, ringsize, aeon

Aeon is a fork of Monero, but it has kept the possibility of zero-mixin transactions which are considered a privacy breach for the CryptoNote protocol generally as they degrade the privacy of the protocol holistically.

What is the reasoning behind keeping 0 mixin capability?  Are there some software engineering trade-offs that mitigate the concerns, or that there is some other benefit that makes this capability valuable for Aeon where it would not be for Monero?